# Re-using a variable in python to store a list of data to add to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, math, finance

**Context**

Following on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67167609/14388939) question, I was able to create three new columns for variable rates of returns as displayed below.

```
    Regular Contribution    Return/Loss Balance Monthly returns Variable Return/Loss    Variable Return Balance
Date                        
2021-04-30  100 1.250000e+01    1.012500e+03    0.000000    0.000000e+00    1.009000e+05
2021-05-31  100 1.390625e+01    1.126406e+03    0.010016    1.865492e+06    1.511990e+08
2021-06-30  100 1.533008e+01    1.241736e+03    0.013418    2.499015e+06    2.025121e+08
2021-07-31  100 1.677170e+01    1.358508e+03    -0.009173   -1.708369e+06   -1.382708e+08
2021-08-31  100 1.823135e+01    1.476739e+03    -0.013527   -2.519416e+06   -2.039627e+08
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2104-03-31  100 2.625473e+07    2.126633e+09    0.000164    3.045373e+04    2.567542e+06
2104-04-30  100 2.658292e+07    2.153216e+09    0.002226    4.146561e+05    3.368655e+07
2104-05-31  100 2.691521e+07    2.180132e+09    0.004802    8.942742e+05    7.253388e+07
2104-06-30  100 2.725165e+07    2.207383e+09    -0.000907   -1.688402e+05   -1.357455e+
```

**The variable returns were derived by calculating returns of a set of assets' annual returns then dividing by 12 as illustrated in the below code.

The problem however is that, I am unable to use the same variable twice in the for loop (capital_insert):

```
for date in date_range:
    # fixed return
    current_return_loss = (interest_rate/12) * capital_insert
    return_losses.append(current_return_loss)
    balances.append(capital_insert + current_return_loss)
    capital_insert += (current_return_loss + Additional_contribution)
    fixed_r = capital_insert
    # variable return
    current_var_return_loss = (var_rtns/12) * capital_insert 
    Var_rtn_balance = current_var_return_loss+var_capital_insert
    capital_insert += (current_var_return_loss + Additional_contribution)
    var_capital_insert = capital_insert
```

This returns this:

```
pd.concat([fixed_r, var_capital_insert], axis=1)

    0   0
0   8.49966762e+30  8.49966762e+30
1   1.02794206e+32  1.02794206e+32
2   2.39554936e+32  2.39554936e+32
3   8.65418098e+29  8.65418098e+29
4   2.92365668e+29  2.92365668e+29
... ... ...
994 1.82899073e+31  1.82899073e+31
995 8.85282386e+30  8.85282386e+30
996 1.47948140e+31  1.47948140e+31
997 2.80848428e+31  2.80848428e+31
998 6.78230893e+30  6.78230893e+30
```

I would normally just change the variable name but I am currently using this to build a web app which I am using this input variable to create the chart (In the chart below, this is the `Initial value`.
[image: Webapp]

Creating a new variable would be possible and could use that in a new data input box, but I wanted to see if there was a way of doing this before going that route.

**Problem**

Is it possible to use the same variable `capital_insert` twice in the for loop to create columns for the final balance of the fixed rate of return and variable rate of return balances?

**Runnable Example**

```
# Portfolio
portfolio = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Regular Contribution', 'Return/Loss', 'Balance', 'Monthly returns', 'Variable Return/Loss', 'Variable Return Balance'])

interest_rate = 0.15
Additional_contribution = 100   
# start data
today = datetime.date.today()
date_range = pd.date_range(start=today, periods=1000, freq='m') # date
    
investment = [Additional_contribution]*len(date_range)
return_losses = []
balances = []
var_return_losses = []
var_return_balance = []
capital_insert = 1000
var_capital_insert = 1000
var_rtns = Portfolio.iloc[0:999]

for date in date_range:
    # fixed return
    current_return_loss = (interest_rate/12) * capital_insert
    return_losses.append(current_return_loss)
    balances.append(capital_insert + current_return_loss)
    capital_insert += (current_return_loss + Additional_contribution) # balance for fixed rate of return
    # fixed_r = capital_insert

    # variable return
    current_var_return_loss = (var_rtns/12) * capital_insert 
    Var_rtn_balance = current_var_return_loss+var_capital_insert
    var_capital_insert += (current_var_return_loss + Additional_contribution) # balance for variable rate of return
    # var_capital_insert = capital_insert

portfolio['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(date_range).date
portfolio['Regular Contribution'] = investment
portfolio['Return/Loss'] = return_losses
portfolio['Balance'] = balances
portfolio['Monthly returns'] = var_rtns
portfolio['Variable Return/Loss'] = current_var_return_loss
portfolio['Variable Return Balance'] = Var_rtn_balance

portfolio.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

balance_at_end = balances[-1]
var_balance_at_end = Var_rtn_balance.iloc[-1]
```

Comment: Please, avoid [posting images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). It is a better practice to transcribe them instead.

Comment: Sure thing, sorted now, thanks

Comment: I don't quite follow. The variable name can be reused, but if you want it to take on a new value you need to reassign it with some kind of `capital_insert= something`. Where is that variable first defined? it's not defined in the for loop, just modified.

Comment: Oh perhaps I understand. You cannot use the same variable to _accumulate_ throughout the for loop. You would need different variables to store the compounding contributions of `fixed_r `and `var_capital_insert`

Comment: If you have a complete, _runnable_ example it may be easier to offer suggestions.

Comment: Runnable example is attached, though not with the variable rates of return function, this was collated from a set of stocks I have saved on an excel sheet.

Comment: you can't keep two values in one variable at the same time - if it is not `list`, `dictionary`, `tuple` or other more complex structure. And you try to keep two values at the same time.

Comment: This is a great idea, a list of lists or list of dictionaries. Then call out one segment for the upper part of the function (fixed rate) and the latter for the other part (variable rate). Thanks!